# Azure HTTP Function Code Query Parameter?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, query-string

I am building an Azure function that uses a query parameter named code. This is an issue, however, because **code** is already used by Azure to pass in the function key. My problem is that I need my query parameter to be called code. What is my best option to accomplish this? I have tried changing the auth level to ANONYMOUS in hopes that **code** would no longer be required and I could use it for my query parameter instead of the function key. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could set the auth level to `Anonymous` but you would lose a level of security.

You can send the code (API key) as a HTTP header `x-functions-key` instead which would free up the `code` query parameter for your use.

Comment: I could have swore I tried that and it didn't work. I'm going to give it another shot. Thanks @chris.

Comment: @MikeA interesting. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: It turns out that this did not work using the "Test" feature in the Azure Function UI, however it worked using Postman. Thanks for the help!

Comment: How the heck we're supposed to guess that, Microsoft?
Anyways, thanks dude! With Postman worked fine.